# How to make the angle degree circle not so close to the letter?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, degrees

it seems i am trying this

```
$\textit{E}_\pi^\circ$
```

and i get an ugly looking exponent

[image]

how can i fix this circle to not be so close tot he E?

Comment: `$\textit{E}_\pi^{\,\circ}$`

Comment: You could also load the `siunit` package and do `$\si{\textit{E}_\pi\degree}$`.

Comment: Or you could make it simple: `$E_\pi^\circ$`.

Comment: Don't use `\textit` in math mode!

Comment: @tomacs I agree with you totaly. The user should use `\mathit{...}`.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Well, variables like `E` are already italic in math mode! So gusbrs is right.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Surely. I have considered in my mind in math mode: \mathrm, \mathit, \mathbf. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need `\textit` in math mode. Text (and variables like `E`) will be italicized already. And the result is much better.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$E_\pi^\circ$
\end{document}
```

[image]

A visual comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\textit{E}_\pi^\circ$ (very wrong)

$\mathit{E}_\pi^\circ$ (less wrong)

$E_\pi^\circ$ (right)

\textbf{$\textit{E}_\pi^\circ$} (why the first is very wrong)

\end{document}
```

[image]

The last example shows that `\textit{E}` is not only wrong for the bad spacing, but also because `\textit` will inherit attributes of the text font current when the formula started.

Comment: Well, @egreg, thanks for the addition. I guess that's the only way an answer of mine will reach "egreg-level"  :).  But should I convert it to CW? (I'd gladly do it). I originally answered in the "solve the OP's problem" spirit. I has now become something more elaborate.

Comment: Leave it as is. I just added the visual comparison for the OP to understand better what's going on.

Comment: Happy to (alongside with the OP) learn from it. Thanks! @egreg